# shrinking covariance matrix for assets coming from different asset class

Tags: portfolio-management

From this paper: [Ledoit, Olivier, and Michael Wolf. "Honey, I shrunk the sample covariance matrix." (2003).](http://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-ffff-ffffb4762fbf/honey.pdf)

I learned a way of shrinking the covariance matrix to get more robust portfolio optimization performance. Yet in the note #4, it says,

> The constant correlation model would not be appropriate if the assets
>   came from different asset classes, such as stocks and bonds. But in
>   such cases more general models for the shrinkage target are available.

Does anyone know any such "more general models"? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of the model "all stocks i,j have the same correlation $\phi$" we would need to implement the model "the correlation between any two stocks is $\phi$, the correlation between any two bonds is $\psi$ and the correlation between a stock and a bond is $\eta$. So we would have three parameters in the correlation matrix model (that we shrink towards) rather than one. How to actually implement this mathematically I know not.

Comment: @AlexC, thanks! Do you know of any paper on this question?

Comment: No, because the whole subject of stock-bond correlation is a literature in and of itself. So the covariance of any stock to any bond is a function of each asset to its asset class, plus a time-varying cross-asset-class covariance. The latter is easiest thought-of as the effect of 1bp on yields to % change in stocks (and vice versa). This translates to a decomposition of nominal interest rates: how much is stronger growth, how much is tighter monetary policy, and how much is inflationary pressures? If you can't exogenously model that, then stock:bond correlation is noise, seen only ex-post.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, Gianluca de Nard has published [Oops! I Shrunk the Sample Covariance Matrix Again: Blockbuster Meets Shrinkage](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3400062), which works out the idea eluded to in the comments explicitly.